# UIlocalNotification not seen in Real Device in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am using UIlocal notification on my response from server, When i run the app on simulator it shows notification in my notification area of Image sent to server,but when you run same app on real device it shows nothing in my notification area, the code is fine but i'm not getting why it is not showing anything, please help me.
My code is,

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = res;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Image Sent";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

and in my AppDelegate.m file it is written as this,

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);}
```

and when i run app on simulator it shows like this , but when i run on real device it shows nothing like this
[image]

Comment: Did you allow notifications on your device?

Comment: are you enrolled in the apple developer program (99$ a year)?

Comment: yes when i first time open app on my device it asked permission. @АлександрКолесник

Comment: No. @MohammadBashirSidani

Comment: Try by enabling background mode in capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in appdelegate and call it from didfinishlaunchwithoption

```
-(void)registerForLocalNotification{
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                       settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|
                                                       UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have u check my code , i have added that in my Appdelegate.m file ? @KavyaKavita

Comment: where? please check your question, you must have posted half code. Not able to loacate registerUserNotificationSettings this method in your code

Comment: are you getting permission alert on first launch? You need to delete app from your device and reinstall it

Comment: yes it ask permission and i allow it but it again don't show any notification. @KavyaKavita

Comment: Try by enabling background mode in capabilities

Comment: how to enable that? @KavyaKavita

Comment: Project -> Target -> capabilities -> Background mode

Comment: Have to on the remote notification? and what to write in info.plist related to Background Mode is on? @KavyaKavita

Comment: you can add anything for now for testing

Comment: Please clear me one thing, when my image sending method is call and image go to server and it gives me response1 of images sent will the notification show in notification area while the app is still running or  will it be shown when the app is close? @KavyaKavita

Comment: when app is close, in background mode, and that what you want right ?